# lazy loading and multiple transactions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am a bit confused with the lazy iterators and multiple transactions in one hibernate session. There is following code block:

```
@Transactional
public void runtProcessing() {
HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = ...
Session hibernateSession = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Iterator<DomainObject> domainObjects = hibernateTemplate.iterate(...);
            try {
                while (domainObjects.hasNext()) {
                    hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
                    DomainObject domainObject = domainObjects.next();

                    processDomainObject(domainObject);
                    hibernateSession.getTransaction().commit();
                }
}
```

As there are multiple transactions, I wonder what transaction does iterator work in?

Answer (score 0):

From here http://ayende.com/blog/3775/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged

> When we don't define our own transactions, we fall back into implicit
>   transaction mode, in which every statement to the database run in its
>   own transaction, resulting in a higher performance cost (database time
>   to build and tear down transactions) and reduced consistency.

thus the iterator is running as part of its own transaction. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Updated code with `@Transactional` annotation. There is already an opened transaction.